# Rename first part of multiple files with mv

Tags: bash, mv

In a directory there are these files and more:

- file1.txt
- file1.html
- file1.pdf
- ...

Every *file1* should be replaced with *newfile*:

- newfile.txt
- newfile.html
- newfile.pdf
- ...

I've tried:

```
for f in $(ls file1*); do mv $f newfile*; done
```

this does replace **all** files with *file1* to one file *newfile**.

```
for f in $(ls file1*); do mv $f ${f/$f/"newfile"}; done
```

this also replaces **all** files with *file1* to one file *newfile*.
Or

```
find . -name "file1.*" -exec sh -c 'mv I DONT KNOW' _ {} \;
```

I don't understand how to set a part of the file name as a variable and replace this.

What is the simplest way to do this with mv?

Answer (score 8):

If you are running on Linux, then the easiest way to achieve it is to use `rename` (which is part of the `util-linux` package:

```
rename 'file1' 'newfile' file1*
```

This will do what you described.  The `rename` expects three arguments:

1. what to look for in the filename
2. what to use as a replacement
3. a file mask to work on

I quickly searched on `rename` and this was the first hit with examples: http://linux.icydog.net/rename.php

*UPDATE* If you don't have `rename` on your system, but do have `bash`, then you can do a batch rename as follows (this is an equivalent of `rename` given above):

```
for f in file1*; do mv -v "$f" "${f/file1/newfile}"; done
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
for f in ./file1.*; do
  echo mv "$f" "newfile.${f##*.}"
done
```

The code only displays what the mv commands will be. When this is what you want, remove the `echo` in front of the mv command.

Answer (score 3):

On Debian-based systems, the `rename` utility is Perl rename and has a slightly different syntax:

```
rename 's/file1/newfile/' file1*
```

The first argument is a Perl expression that will be applied to each file name found.

Answer (score 1):

Use expr to get the last part of each name. I am assuming here that you know the prefix is "file1" otherwise you might need another loop.

```
for f in $(ls file1.*)
do
suffix=`expr $f : '.*\.\(.*\)'`
mv -v file1.${suffix} newfile.${suffix}
done
```

Note that to do this properly, you might want to check that the destination doesn't already exist, or you could use the "-n" flag on mv to avoid clobbering an existing file.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU find:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "file1*" -printf "%f\0" | xargs -0 -I {} echo mv -v {} new{}
```

If everything looks okay, remove `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @cuonglm's answer, I found out what was missing:

```
find . -name "file1.*" -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "newfile.${1##*.}"' _ {} \;
```